# How to pass and use data from react native to native android or ios?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need to pass some data form react native to both native android and ios.

How can I do that?

thank you,

Comment: what does this means?

Comment: hi @GauravRoy , ok I will explain: for example I have my state object like this : this.state={color: "#ffaa00" } I want to use this color value inside android forder, in layout folder (ex: layout.xml file : android:background= this.state.color, that means I want to use the state color for a layout background). Hope now it's clear

Comment: @hanae I know I am too late on this, but for future references, people can look at this for [Android] (https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-android#passing-properties-from-react-native-to-native) and [iOS] (https://reactnative.dev/docs/communication-ios#passing-properties-from-react-native-to-native).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to communicate with natives modules in a react native app, you should take a look at these examples of Native Modules. This is for ios https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios and this is for android https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

Comment: hey, thanks but I have already seen this documentation that shows you how to pass properties from native to react native but this is not what i want (I want to pass data from react native to native)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a native method that expects parameters, like this:

```
@ReactMethod
public void createCalendarEvent(String name, String location) {
   Log.d("CalendarModule", "Create event called with name: " + name
   + " and location: " + location);
}
```

The native side receives its parameters and uses it in the native method:

```
CalendarModule.createCalendarEvent('testName', 'testLocation');
```

[You can see more here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android)

Answer (score 0):

this question is a year ago, but maybe someone still wondering how to pass from react native to native (android).
i found answer from `David Vittori` indeed there is documentation.

to simplify you can do this step:

1. (native android) create java class like this:

```
public class ExamplePackage implements ReactPackage {
    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
        modules.add(new ExampleModule(reactContext));
        return modules;
    }
}
```

2. (native android) then in `MainApplication.java`, in method `getPackages()` add this:

   `packages.add(new ExamplePackage());`
3. (native android) create java class like `ExampleModule.java`:

```
    public class ExampleModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
        Activity activity;
        public ExampleModule(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
            super(reactContext);
        }
        @Nonnull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "ExampleModule";
        }
        @ReactMethod(isBlockingSynchronousMethod = true)
        public void MinimizeExample(String params) {
            activity = getCurrentActivity();
            Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "triggered by react native with params: " + params, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

4. finally in your react native either you put it on screen or component, call the method like this:

```
    import { NativeModules } from "react-native";
    const { ExampleModule } = NativeModules;
    const ExampleDetail = ({ navigation }) => {
      const onButtonPressed = () => {
        ExampleModule.MinimizeExample("passing params to native android");
      };
    };
```